# How to use AFNetworking with multiple UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, afnetworking, multiple-instances

For example, one `UIViewController` requests data using AFNetworking on appear event and perform some actions on result receiving. These actions are defined in a block which I give to a request object as a param.

Now I want to add a button which will push another view controller. This view controller will use the same data which the first view controller already uses.

The problem is I don't need to resend the same request for the second one but I'll have some issues with it:
1)I can't set its params directly on request completion because the second view controller may not exist yet
2)If the second one is currently displayed then should I handle the data in the first one?

To handle requests I create `NSURLSessionTask` object and call `showAlertViewForTaskWithErrorOnCompletion:delegate:`. It is just two strings of code so I think it is not necessary to post it.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally it sounds like you are trying to share data between view controllers. There are multiple solutions to this problem, refer to this answer:

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

For checking which is the displayed view controller, consult this answer:

[How to determine which view controller is currently active/the one displaying a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255599/how-to-determine-which-view-controller-is-currently-active-the-one-displaying-a)

Comment: Fundamentally you posted some links with theory which are not connected with both AFNetworking or asynchronous calls.